# Cutting protruding nails between roof and angled ceiling

Tags: ceiling, roof, nails, metal-cutting, angle-grinder

I'd like to insulate ceiling under the small attic-like part of the house. The problem is, that from the inside, long nails have been driven through the wood planks of the ceiling, protruding into the space between the roof and the top side of the ceiling - including the very restricted space between the angled roof part and the angled ceiling, making it impossible to install the vapor barrier:

[image: Angled ceiling, roof, nails]

Green is the planned insulation - sorry, drawing not to scale... How could I cut these nails without demolishing the ceiling itself?

What I thought about: have a thin enough angle grinder and construct an attachment that would allow it to slide stable, and guide the nails and support the grinder physically - and add a contraption that allows the whole thing to be moved from the attic. Additionally, I could add my $10 endoscope cam for some sights in the space.

[image: Crazy angle grinder contraption plan]

**Note**: the disc would be spinning "away" from the attachment, so it would not pull the nails toward the machine itself, but the other way: it would be pushing the thing away.

Is there something better?

**EDIT:** I wonder how much force is required to operate this:

[image: snipper with a ratio]

Comment: watch for sparks that will start fire

Comment: @Ruskes Thanks - yes that would need to be handled appropriately. Thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Why not just find the nails using a magnet or metal detector and pull them?  Replace with screws or adjacent nails of proper length to avoid the protruding.  Might need to so some mudding  after, but that seems a lot easier than remotely piloting an angle grinder.

Comment: How much space is there in inches/cm/feet?  Sparks in a tight space with very dry wood and dust is not good.  Cutting/snipping or bending would be much safer.

Comment: How much space is there for tools? If access were available, cutting ordinary (not hardened) nails with a diagonal gutter is not difficult. Likely not worth the effort of building, but a hydraulic tool like a tonsil snare might be made: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-9PHML_TSSOc/TwWjMnt3C5I/AAAAAAAAADs/Ks7Upjm4n-s/s1600/Tonsil+snare1.jpg

Comment: @Huesmann hmm didn't think of this - not sure,  if I could find the nails from the inside, the plaster is at least 2 cm thick under which their heads are... Also, I think as there are lots of these, like a hundred, it'd require a lot of aftercare... Maybe if all else fails, the solution would be to tear everything down and redo it with more modern approach like proper insulation and gypsum board....

Comment: @crip659 I'd need to measure it properly, but it is quite small... I'd say more than 10cm but less than 15. I can slightly have more: there is some outdated insulation present on the inside of the roof which at one point I'd like to get rid of anyway... I agree that sparks are not a good idea here. Will try to see what I can come up with regards to snipping and bending...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik hmmm, hydraulics didn't come to my mind but it is an option...

Comment: As suggested by others here, why not bend over the protruding nails? Perhaps just pushing a 2x4 or 4x4 down between the surfaces would be sufficient to bend over the nail ends.

Comment: @ppeterka if you can deal with the demo involved, simply replacing the ceiling with gypsum board might be less fiddly work than cutting or bashing over a hundred nails within the confines of the 10 cm space.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that a suitable mechanical nipper is safer and possibly *more* effective than a power tool.

Or you could just cleat down the nail points?